# RenderSection is not working correctly (Razor, MVC, ASP)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have defined **Header** into **_Layout**

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
{

    @RenderSection("_Header")
    @Html.Partial("_Header")
}
else
{
 <header>Home</header>
}
```

Inside page, where I use layout I have defined section as below:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

@section _Header{ }

 <div>
   <!-- some code -->
 </div>

@section _Footer{ }
```

And code is crashed:

```
InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been 
defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml':'_Header'
To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").
```

When I have changed to:

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false
```

It's working fine.

Why I got this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just found answer:

```
<body>

    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Header")
    }
    else
    {
        <header>Home</header>
    }    

    @RenderBody()    

    @RenderSection("_Header", required: false)

</body>
```